# Is it possible to backup and restore azure log analytics if disaster happens?

Tags: azure, backup, restore, azure-monitoring

Currently I used the Azure Log Analytics to monitor azure resources effectively. But when I used the log analytics for production environment, in some cases disaster happen in some data center at that time I restored all azure resources like app service, api management, SQL database and cosmos dB etc..  Even disaster happens. But I can’t restore the log analytics because currently there is no backup option for it in azure portal.

So, can you please tell me how to backup and restore azure log analytics if disaster happens?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is anything currently which can achieve both things.

My solution to backing up log analytics is to use the az cli interface with the log-analytics extension and periodically dump all events to disk.

e.g.

az monitor log-analytics query -w "" --analytics-query 'Event | sort by TimeGenerated desc' > log

limit your query by hour or day to avoid return result limitations and run on an appropriate schedule.

you could then upload the log file to a blob storage as needed.